# Creating a Makefile

Tags: make

I am wondering how to create a Makefile to compile `hello.c`:

```c
// for example

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

I am aware that I compile the program by the help off `gcc hello.c -o hello` and how I run it but that is as much as i know at the moment.

Comment: I don't understand what Bash has to do with it. Other than that, what have you tried?

Comment: It's also unclear what "converting from sudo" means. Sudo is an utility that allows you to run things as another user(as root for instance). [Here is a very basic Makefile tutorial](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/).

Comment: You need to learn (1) how Makefiles are written (their "language": syntax and semantics), and (2) how to create a file and write something to it when you are using bash. Which question do you want to be answered? As for (1), look into the manual for `make` (with `info make`). As for (2), the answer will be the same -- no matter whether you want to create a "Makefile" or some other kind of a plain text file. If your question is (2), please make it more clear by making the question more general and mentioning Makefile only as an example. Otherwise it's confusing for us: (1) or (2)?

Comment: Please restate your question in a more sensible way: You converted from "sudo"? `sudo` is a shell command to get privileged access. I suggest you take your time stating your question more carefully!

Comment: I've edited out references to `bash` and `sudo` since they do not really have much of anything to do with the question.

Comment: @goldilocks y u forgot the tags :P

Answer (score 2):

GNU make has a very substantial [online manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), and while IMO it is aggravating and obtuse at many points, it does make a decent reference.  As others have said, just look around for a tutorial that works for you, and consult the manual along with that so you get used how it is organized, etc.

A basic (GNU make) makefile for building `hello.c` might look like:

```
CFLAGS += -Wall -g -O0
PROGS = hello

.PHONY: clean

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    -rm $(PROGS)
```

`$(CC)` is a [built-in variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc_Name-Index); if you don't redefine it, the default is `cc`, which on a GNU system will be a symlink to `gcc`.  `%` indicates a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro); in this case it will match *anything*, although if there is no `anything.c` in the directory the recipe will fail.  `$<` and `$@` are [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables). So if you now run:

```
make hello
```

Make will execute:

```
cc -Wall -g -O0 hello.c -o hello
```

Using `+=` with `$(CFLAGS) allows you to do stuff like this:

```
CFLAGS="--std=c99" make hello
```

So that `-Wall -g -O0` will be appended to `--std=c99`, separated by a space.  Note that if you use `make CFLAGS="--std=c99" hello`, that value will *replace* any definition in the makefile.

Rules have three basic parts, the *targets*, the *prerequisites*, and the *recipe* ([see here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax)).  The rule will run if:

- The target file does not exist.
- The target file is older than one of the prerequisites.

`.PHONY` targets will run no matter what.  So running `make clean` with the above make file will execute:

```
rm hello
```

In this case `$(PROGS)` is not used anywhere else, although in a more complex project make file it might be used as a prerequisite for something else.  E.g., if you add this rule to the top (after the variable declarations):

```
all: $(PROGS)
```

And append `all` to the `.PHONY:` list, you can now just enter `make` and everything in the `$(PROGS)` list will be built using the `%: %.c` rule, since this is a prerequisite to make `all`, and `all` is the first rule in the file -- used by default if you don't specify one (i.e., you can still use `make hello` to build just the "hello" program).

Answer (score 1):

To create an appropriate Makefile, one needs these two things:

- Macros
- Rules

Macros are what we use in Makefiles to shorten the syntax and make it easier to edit the file if something has changed. For example:

```
C = gcc # sets the macro for the C compiler to C
```

And so `$(C)` can be substituted for `gcc`

Rules are what are used for checking the changes of files and their dependencies. There must always be an `all` rule so that when `make` is run, it checks the `all` rule first. Just like your C program, where the `main()` function is executed first.

Example Makefile:

```
C = gcc
CFLAGS = -o
INPUT = hello
OUT = $(INPUT)

all: $(INPUT)

$(OUT): $(INPUT).c
        $(C) $(INPUT).cpp $(CFLAGS) $(OUT)
```

A rule can be declared by giving its name + a semicolon (e.g. `do_this:`), adding any dependant files or rules after it (e.g. `another_rule $(DEPENDANDTFILE)`) and then adding commands on the next line after a TAB.

NOTE: Rules will not work unless there is a TAB at the beggining of the statement's line.

Comment: Using `$(OUT)` as an exact duplicate of `$(INPUT)` seems pointless and confusing.  Also the suffix should really be `.c`, to match the question and the value of `$(c)`.

Comment: To me it would seem a little confusing to use `$(INPUT)` for the name of the rule, so I created another macro `$(OUT)` to take away my confusion. Whether or not you find using `$(OUT)` confusing seems to depend on the person. What would you suggest that I use as a name? Ah, yes. The `.cpp`, I was just using C++ and completely didn't realise that it was C we were using! My bad! :)

Comment: There is a lot of leeway WRT to style and preference in makefiles.  If you are used to using "input" and "output" semantics, fair enough, but it seems simpler here if you just replace both of them with, e.g. `PROGRAMS`, since they the same.  Also, **using them in the recipe line is a bad idea** (think what will happen if you add another item to that list). You should als edit the recipe now, since it refers to a `.cpp` file but the prerequisite is a `.c`.